# Csv DictReader throwing error for fieldnames

Tags: python, csv

I have a piece of code that has been working for a while that uses Python’s DictReader.

The code initializes the csv reader, `csv_reader = csv.DictReader(my_csv)` and then I access `csv_reader.fieldnames`. Historically this has been working fine.

However today it started throwing this error `iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)` when I try to access `csv_reader.fieldnames`.

`csv_reader.__dict__` shows an object with an attribute `_fieldnames`, and it is empty. I’m not sure why this changed or what I can do to resolve it, any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How do you open `my_csv`?

Comment: @IainShelvington I open it like `csv_file = open(self.bulk_file_path, 'rU')`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to specify your file's `encoding` explicitly:

```
with (open('my.csv', 'rt', encoding='utf-8')) as file:
```